# Dynamics 365 Search Resource Availability

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

I am attempting to implement the Search Resource Capability as described here: https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/dynamics365/it/2019/05/21/retrieve-resource-availability-with-universal-resource-scheduling-api/

There is an example here of how to implement it via JavaScript (although the JavaScript libraries are probably deprecated or unsupported), which I have referenced here: https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/dynamics365/it/2019/07/15/how-to-use-resource-schedulings-search-resource-availability-api/

I have written a .NET Core Class Library that uses the Dynamics 365 OData Service to POST to the msdyn_SearchResourceAvailability Action.

I have seen some examples on the internet, but they all use the Dynamics 365 SDK, not the Dynamics 365 Web API.

I am getting an error and have therefore extracted the JSON that is being posted and tried the same call in Postman, where I am getting the same error:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "0x0",
    "message": "An error occurred while validating input parameters: Microsoft.OData.ODataException: Does not support untyped value in non-open type.\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Deserialization.DeserializationHelpers.ApplyProperty(ODataProperty property, IEdmStructuredTypeReference resourceType, Object resource, ODataDeserializerProvider deserializerProvider, ODataDeserializerContext readContext)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Deserialization.ODataResourceDeserializer.ApplyStructuralProperties(Object resource, ODataResourceWrapper resourceWrapper, IEdmStructuredTypeReference structuredType, ODataDeserializerContext readContext)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.CrmODataEntityDeserializer.ApplyStructuralProperties(Object resource, ODataResourceWrapper resourceWrapper, IEdmStructuredTypeReference structuredType, ODataDeserializerContext readContext)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Deserialization.ODataResourceDeserializer.ReadResource(ODataResourceWrapper resourceWrapper, IEdmStructuredTypeReference structuredType, ODataDeserializerContext readContext)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.ODataV4.CrmODataActionPayloadDeserializer.ReadEntry(ODataDeserializerContext readContext, ODataParameterReader reader, IEdmOperationParameter parameter)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.ODataV4.CrmODataActionPayloadDeserializer.Read(ODataMessageReader messageReader, Type type, ODataDeserializerContext readContext)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStream(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)",
    "innererror": {
        "message": "An error occurred while validating input parameters: Microsoft.OData.ODataException: Does not support untyped value in non-open type.\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Deserialization.DeserializationHelpers.ApplyProperty(ODataProperty property, IEdmStructuredTypeReference resourceType, Object resource, ODataDeserializerProvider deserializerProvider, ODataDeserializerContext readContext)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Deserialization.ODataResourceDeserializer.ApplyStructuralProperties(Object resource, ODataResourceWrapper resourceWrapper, IEdmStructuredTypeReference structuredType, ODataDeserializerContext readContext)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.CrmODataEntityDeserializer.ApplyStructuralProperties(Object resource, ODataResourceWrapper resourceWrapper, IEdmStructuredTypeReference structuredType, ODataDeserializerContext readContext)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Deserialization.ODataResourceDeserializer.ReadResource(ODataResourceWrapper resourceWrapper, IEdmStructuredTypeReference structuredType, ODataDeserializerContext readContext)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.ODataV4.CrmODataActionPayloadDeserializer.ReadEntry(ODataDeserializerContext readContext, ODataParameterReader reader, IEdmOperationParameter parameter)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.ODataV4.CrmODataActionPayloadDeserializer.Read(ODataMessageReader messageReader, Type type, ODataDeserializerContext readContext)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStream(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)",
        "type": "Microsoft.Crm.CrmHttpException",
        "stacktrace": "   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataUtilities.ValidateInputParameters(ModelStateDictionary controllerModelState)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.ActionController.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<PostUnboundAction>b__0()\r\n   at Microsoft.PowerApps.CoreFramework.ActivityLoggerExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger logger, EventId eventId, ActivityType activityType, Func`1 func, IEnumerable`1 additionalCustomProperties)\r\n   at Microsoft.Xrm.Telemetry.XrmTelemetryExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger logger, XrmTelemetryActivityType activityType, Func`1 func)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
    }
}
}
```

The JSON that is being posted is as follows:

```
{
"Version": "1",
"Requirement": {
    "msdyn_duration": 180,
    "msdyn_effort": 1,
    "msdyn_fromdate": "2020-03-10T00:00:00+00:00",
    "msdyn_latitude": 55.784129,
    "msdyn_longitude": -3.982742,
    "msdyn_name": "Super Heroes Resource Requirement",
    "msdyn_remainingduration": 180,
    "msdyn_todate": "2020-03-12T00:00:00+00:00",
    "msdyn_worklocation": 690970002
},
"Settings": {
    "ConsiderSlotsWithLessThanRequiredCapacity": false,
    "ConsiderSlotsWithLessThanRequiredDuration": false,
    "ConsiderTravelTime": false,
    "ConsiderSlotsWithOverlappingBooking": false,
    "ConsiderSlotsWithProposedBookings": false,
    "MovePastStartDateToCurrentDate": false,
    "UseRealTimeResourceLocation": false,
    "MaxResourceTravelRadius": {
        "Value": 10,
        "Unit": 192350000
    },
    "SortOrder": {
        "value": [
            {
                "Name": "bookableresource",
                "SortOrder": 0
            }
        ]
    }
},
"ResourceSpecification": {
    "ResourceTypes": {
        "value": [
            2,
            3,
            5
        ]
    },
    "PreferredResources": {
        "value": [
            {
                "bookableresourceid": "d7315245-b162-ea11-a811-000d3a0bad7c"
            },
            {
                "bookableresourceid": "b54bc744-b162-ea11-a811-000d3a0ba110"
            }
        ]
    },
    "RestrictedResources": {
        "value": [
            {
                "bookableresourceid": "ba6d4a4b-b162-ea11-a811-000d3a0bad7c"
            },
            {
                "bookableresourceid": "ca6d4a4b-b162-ea11-a811-000d3a0bad7c"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Constraints": {
        "Characteristics": {
            "value": [
                {
                    "characteristicid": "a02db73e-b162-ea11-a811-000d3a0ba110"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Roles": {
            "value": [
                {
                    "bookableresourcecategoryid": "d56d4a4b-b162-ea11-a811-000d3a0bad7c"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Territories": {
            "value": [
                {
                    "territoryid": "7c2db73e-b162-ea11-a811-000d3a0ba110"
                }
            ]
        },
        "UnspecifiedTerritory": false,
        "OrganizationalUnits": {
            "value": [
                {
                    "msdyn_organizationalunitid": "822db73e-b162-ea11-a811-000d3a0ba110"
                }
            ]
        },
        "BusinessUnits": {
            "value": [
                {
                    "businessunitid": "fba6cf4b-f24a-ea11-a813-00224801cd21"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
}
```

Could anyone please advise where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a couple of things:

You should now be able to call msdyn_SearchResourceAvailability via Web API.

Key Tasks:

- Vesrion 3 is being used
- “IsWebApi”: true is specified
- Proper “@odata.type” annotations for nested objects are provided

Sample:

```
{

    "Version": "3",

    "IsWebApi": true,

    "Requirement": {

        "msdyn_fromdate": "2021-08-17T00:00:00Z",

        "msdyn_todate": "2021-08-18T23:59:00Z",

        "msdyn_remainingduration": 60,

        "msdyn_duration": 60,

        "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.msdyn_resourcerequirement"

    },

    "Settings": {

        "ConsiderSlotsWithProposedBookings": false,

        "MovePastStartDateToCurrentDate": true,

        "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.expando"

    },

    "ResourceSpecification": {

        "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.expando",

        "ResourceTypes@odata.type": "Collection(Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.expando)",

        "ResourceTypes": [

            {

                "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.expando",

                "value": "1"

            },

            {

                "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.expando",

                "value": "2"

            }

        ]

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to upgrade to Field service v8.8.x from v8.7.x and test the CRM action `msdyn_SearchResourceAvailability` using web api with the following payload. I don't have all the config & data setup it seems but the web api is resulting good response (different than 400 = Bad request.. lol)

```
var parameters = {};
parameters.Version = "2";
var requirement = {};
requirement.msdyn_resourcerequirementid = "B9E6F413-0063-EA11-A811-000D3A5A1CAC"; //Delete if creating new record 
requirement["@odata.type"] = "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.msdyn_resourcerequirement";
parameters.Requirement = requirement;
var settings = {};
settings.systemuserid = "26ADDD07-D9F4-E711-8138-E0071B715B11"; //Delete if creating new record 
settings["@odata.type"] = "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.systemuser";
parameters.Settings = settings;

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.1/msdyn_SearchResourceAvailability", true);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 200) {
            var results = JSON.parse(this.response);
            alert(this.response)
        } else {
            alert(this.status);
        }
    }
};
req.send(JSON.stringify(parameters));
```

Response:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://crmdev.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/$metadata#Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.msdyn_SearchResourceAvailabilityResponse",
  "TimeSlots": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.organization"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.organization"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.organization"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.organization"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.organization"
    }
  ],
  "Resources": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.organization"
    }
  ],
  "Related": {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.organization"
  },
  "Exceptions": {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.organization"
  }
}
```

---

Update:

1. Only Version, Requirement, and Settings are required for this call, so start with minimal code input & enhance it
2. While troubleshooting the error message `Microsoft.OData.ODataException: Does not support untyped value in non-open type`, proceed in this direction - [typo in some schema name could be the reason](https://d365demystified.com/2020/01/02/what-is-does-not-support-untyped-value-in-non-open-type-odataexception-in-creating-records-in-d365-ce/)
3. Not sure if this `msdyn_SearchResourceAvailability` action message is yet available in web api, but only `OrganizationRequest` SDK is tried out [Reference](https://community.dynamics.com/365/fieldservice/f/dynamics-365-for-field-service-forum/375216/how-to-get-available-time-slots-from-new-api-urs-unified-resource-scheduling-using-plug-ins-code)

---

This is the sample request along with required payload:

```
var parameters = {};
var workorder = {};
workorder.msdyn_workorderid = "ADE6F413-0063-EA11-A811-000D3A5A1CAC"; //Delete if creating new record 
workorder["@odata.type"] = "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.msdyn_workorder";
parameters.WorkOrder = workorder;
parameters.RealTimeMode = true;
parameters.Duration = 30;
parameters.IgnoreDuration = true;
parameters.IgnoreTravelTime = true;
parameters.AllowOverlapping = true;
parameters.Radius = 0;
parameters.StartTime = new Date("3/10/2020").toISOString();
parameters.EndTime = new Date("3/10/2020").toISOString();
var resources1 = {};
resources1.systemuserid = "3BD2ADED-20B2-E911-A98E-000D3A374B53"; //Delete if creating new record 
resources1["@odata.type"] = "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.systemuser";
parameters.Resources = [resources1];

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.1/msdyn_RetrieveResourceAvailability", true);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 200) {
            var results = JSON.parse(this.response);
            alert("response: "+this.response)
        } else {
            alert(this.status);
        }
    }
};
req.send(JSON.stringify(parameters));
```

I just generated this with my sandbox without any data, but you can try the CRM REST builder for building up the request.

Comment: The action I'm using is msdyn_SearchResourceAvailability, not msdyn_RetrieveResourceAvailability. Are you able to call msdyn_SearchResourceAvailability? Can you share the JSON that you get from JSON.stringify(parameters)?

Comment: This also seems to be JavaScript. I'm looking for the C# implementation.

Comment: Actually, the JSON would be fine.

Comment: @JFK007 my bad. do you have a link where you find sdk samples or from where you get your JSON. I could not find any on this topic. I dont see this endpoint in my metadata

Comment: This Action is only available if you install Field Service.

Comment: @JFK007 I have Field service installed. What I mean - msdyn_SearchResourceAvailability is missing. I see msdyn_RetrieveResourceAvailability though.

Comment: @JFK007, pls see my update. I think I have a minimal json payload, but have a long way to go :)

Comment: JSON payload is like this `{
  "Version": "2",
  "Requirement": {
    "msdyn_resourcerequirementid": "B9E6F413-0063-EA11-A811-000D3A5A1CAC",
    "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.msdyn_resourcerequirement"
  },
  "Settings": {
    "systemuserid": "26ADDD07-D9F4-E711-8138-E0071B715B11",
    "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.systemuser"
  }
}`

Comment: It works with the minimal payload, but the problem is when trying to populate Settings or ResourceSpecification populated, where the error is occurring. It seems that these should have odata.type = Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.organization and it doesn't like the attributes. It would be good to get clarity on the correct odata.type to use, perhaps Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.entity or something else. I wonder if the attributes aren't being validated against the odata.type, rather than the actual expected parameters.

Comment: @ArunVinoth you wrote that "I don't have all the config & data setup it seems...", what do you mean by that and did you ever manage to get actual values instead of just "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.organization"?

Comment: Was anyone ever able to figure out more on this?

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that the C# samples out there use the SDK, which in turn uses the deprecated 2011 WCF service, not the current OData Service. It looks as if the OData Service is more strict in terms of the @odata.type you specify, in that it looks to check that the attributes you are providing are real attributes/fields of that entity. The problem with **Settings** and **ResourceSpecification** is that in the *Action*, the type of entity is not specified.

Comment: I reached out to my MS contacts, waiting for their reply,